# PHP + SQL + Android with loop shooting down

Tags: php, android, sql

I'm trying to do a online card game for android with php and mysql... all working, but when I test for a long time my app the server not respond for 5 or 10 minutes for all devices in the same DNS...

I'm trying to get the refresh of SQL with a loop on AssyncTask, something like:

```
while(true){
try{
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Integer.toString(777)));

        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get, "POST", params);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
}
```

Someone can help here? i'm lost!

Thanks!

Comment: I put a "json = null" after the try and
    while(json == null){} after the "makeHttpRequest"...

Make sense? was working...

Comment: Nice [DDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) mobile application you did here... You should at least put in some delay between the iterations - or else that happens what you observed: you overload the infrastructure. The solution posted in the comment could work better, but I'd still add a Thread.sleep(500); for each try...